# Centering two views in a GridLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm truing to make a simple app and in the homepage i need to put 6 cardviews ordered in two colums and three rows.
If i understand correct in the gridlayout there are two columns that occupy exactly half the width of the screen and and there are three row that split the height into three equal parts.
What i want is that in every cell of gridlayout the cardview are centered in it; 
i've tried a solution like `layout_gravity="center"` but the cardviews still remain in the left of the screen, so how can i do that?

This is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
app:columnCount="2"
app:rowCount="3"
android:layout_gravity="center">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:id="@+id/card1"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_card"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/grid_card"
    app:layout_column="0"
    app:layout_row="0" />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:id="@+id/card2"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_card"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/grid_card"
    app:layout_column="1"
    app:layout_row="0" />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:id="@+id/card3"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_card"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/grid_card"
    app:layout_column="0"
    app:layout_row="1" />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:id="@+id/card4"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_card"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/grid_card"
    app:layout_column="1"
    app:layout_row="1" />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:id="@+id/card5"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_card"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/grid_card"
    app:layout_column="0"
    app:layout_row="2" />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:id="@+id/card6"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_card"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/grid_card"
    app:layout_column="1"
    app:layout_row="2"/>


</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these three attributes to each of your `<CardView>` tags:

```
app:layout_gravity="center"
app:layout_columnWeight="1"
app:layout_rowWeight="1"
```

The weight attrs will make sure that each cell in the grid occupies one sixth of the screen, and the gravity attr will make sure that the card is centered within its cell.